# Download Google Slide presentation (published to the web)

Tags: google-slides-api

I would like to download this link as PDF:

> https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vRouwj_3cYsmLrNNI3Uq5gv5-hYp_QFdeoan2GlxKgIZRSejozruAbVV0IMXBoPsINB7Jw92vJo2EAM/pub?slide=id.p

Unfortunately, this URL uses non standard format that I recognise and can manipulate.

Modifying it to something like

> https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/2PACX-1vRouwj_3cYsmLrNNI3Uq5gv5-hYp_QFdeoan2GlxKgIZRSejozruAbVV0IMXBoPsINB7Jw92vJo2EAM/edit

doesn't work.

The Google Drive file ID should be **44** alphanumeric characters, but clearly this is **86** characters long.

Comment: Wrote a blog about this.. https://medium.com/@ajaytvn/how-to-download-google-slide-presentations-published-to-the-web-3c1564bd92c1

Comment: @loxxy that helped, thank you! I used the second bookmarklet only. It expanded the presentation to have all slides on one long page which I then "*printed*" into a PDF. The first bookmarklet didn't work, throwing an error - but I didn't need it anyway, apparently

Answer (score 22):

From this [tutorial](http://www.free-power-point-templates.com/articles/how-to-generate-a-link-to-download-a-google-slides-presentation-as-powerpoint/) to generate a link to download a google slides must have this format:

```
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/<FileID>/export/<format>
```

where `<format>` can be `pptx` or `pdf`.

This way, you can bypass Google Drive viewer or Google Slides editor and create direct download links to include in any web page. The main benefit is that you only need to maintain and host one presentation and then a direct link can be provided for anyone who need to download it in a different format.

Hope this information helps you.

Comment: yes, I already know about that. It puzzles me that the link provided is not in this standard expected format, and yet it links to a valid Google slide presentation; so I wonder how I can download a copy in PDF, since it's publicly accessible.

Comment: Thanks for share, it is working for me.

Comment: This answer completely ignores the op's point about the length of the key.

Comment: This shows "Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist."